# I am using a custom loss function (yolo v2 loss function) , however i am getting loss as nan

Tags: keras, nan, yolo, loss

The below code is inspired from the repo Keras-Yolo-v2 , i am facing issues with the code i am trying to understand the possible causes of loss Nan.
I have already used techniques like clipnorm but that did not help.
This is the custom loss of yolo v2  , i am trying to implement it on Tensorflow 2.0.
I have some idea on this that somewhere the value is becoming 0 and that is resulting in the loss as Nan but i can figure out exactly where that might be happening. I need help in resolving this issue.

```
class YoloLossKeras:

    def __init__(self, priors):
        self.priors = priors

    def loss(self, y_true, y_pred):

        n_cells = y_pred.get_shape().as_list()[1]
        y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, tf.shape(y_pred), name='y_true')
        y_pred = tf.identity(y_pred, name='y_pred')

        #### PROCESS PREDICTIONS ####
        # get x-y coords (for now they are with respect to cell)
        predicted_xy = tf.nn.sigmoid(y_pred[..., :2])

        # convert xy coords to be with respect to image
        cell_inds = tf.range(n_cells, dtype=tf.float32)
        predicted_xy = tf.stack((
            predicted_xy[..., 0] + tf.reshape(cell_inds, [1, -1, 1]), 
            predicted_xy[..., 1] + tf.reshape(cell_inds, [-1, 1, 1])
        ), axis=-1)

        # compute bb width and height
        predicted_wh = self.priors * tf.exp(y_pred[..., 2:4])

        # compute predicted bb center and width
        predicted_min = predicted_xy - predicted_wh / 2
        predicted_max = predicted_xy + predicted_wh / 2

        predicted_objectedness = tf.nn.sigmoid(y_pred[..., 4])
        predicted_logits = tf.nn.softmax(y_pred[..., 5:])


        #### PROCESS TRUE ####
        true_xy = y_true[..., :2]
        true_wh = y_true[..., 2:4]
        true_logits = y_true[..., 5:]

        true_min = true_xy - true_wh / 2
        true_max = true_xy + true_wh / 2

        #### compute iou between ground truth and predicted (used for objectedness) ####
        intersect_mins  = tf.maximum(predicted_min, true_min)
        intersect_maxes = tf.minimum(predicted_max, true_max)
        intersect_wh    = tf.maximum(intersect_maxes - intersect_mins, 0.)
        intersect_areas = intersect_wh[..., 0] * intersect_wh[..., 1]

        true_areas = true_wh[..., 0] * true_wh[..., 1]
        pred_areas = predicted_wh[..., 0] * predicted_wh[..., 1]

        union_areas = pred_areas + true_areas - intersect_areas
        iou_scores  = intersect_areas / union_areas

        #### Compute loss terms ####
        responsibility_selector = y_true[..., 4]

        xy_diff = tf.square(true_xy - predicted_xy) * responsibility_selector[..., None]
        xy_loss = tf.reduce_sum(xy_diff, axis=[1, 2, 3, 4])

        wh_diff = tf.square(tf.sqrt(true_wh) - tf.sqrt(predicted_wh)) * responsibility_selector[..., None]
        wh_loss = tf.reduce_sum(wh_diff, axis=[1, 2, 3, 4])

        obj_diff = tf.square(iou_scores - predicted_objectedness) * responsibility_selector
        obj_loss = tf.reduce_sum(obj_diff, axis=[1, 2, 3])

        best_iou = tf.reduce_max(iou_scores, axis=-1)
        no_obj_diff = tf.square(0 - predicted_objectedness) * tf.cast(best_iou < 0.6,tf.float32)[..., None] * (1 - responsibility_selector)
        no_obj_loss = tf.reduce_sum(no_obj_diff, axis=[1, 2, 3])

        clf_diff = tf.square(true_logits - predicted_logits) * responsibility_selector[..., None]
        clf_loss = tf.reduce_sum(clf_diff, axis=[1, 2, 3, 4])

        object_coord_scale = 5
        object_conf_scale = 1
        noobject_conf_scale = 1
        object_class_scale = 1

        loss = object_coord_scale * (xy_loss + wh_loss) + \
                object_conf_scale * obj_loss + noobject_conf_scale * no_obj_loss + \
                object_class_scale * clf_loss
        return loss
```